# How to store words from a file in a two dimensional array in C

Tags: c, string, file, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read a file like:

mother mama,
father papa,
apple mar,
...

And I would like to store those words in an array of chars A[10][2][12]
so the words :
"mother" will be in A[0][0]
"father" in A[1][0]
but the second column :
"mama" in A[0][0]
"papa" in A[0][1]
...
I can change the format of the words in the file,I can write them without comma or maybe with something else!
I now how to read the word character by character and store them in an array ,but have no idea how to store those pairs in a two dimensional array!!
Appreciate any help or hints)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.   Note: stackoverflow.com is not a free design/coding service.

Comment: suggest implementing a struct that contains a word pair.  Then writing/reading instances of that struct to/from the disk.

Comment: I know thats an option,but I am not allowed to do it using struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding;

*"mother" will be in A[0][0] "father" in A[1][0] but the second column : "mama" in A[0][0] "papa" in A[0][1]*

That will not work.  Suggest:

"mother" will be in A[0][0] "father" in A[1][0]. "mama" in A[0][1] "papa" in A[1][1]